# Does Java Postgresql Driver support Array Datatype, getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Im using Postgres 9.3,  I get the Java database driver like this

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't load org.postgresql.Driver");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Then I do :

```
  Array urlData = rs.getArray("urls");
  String[] urls = (String[]) urlData.getArray();
```

but last line is failing with `NullPointerException` because urlData is null

Why is this, is Array not supported for Postgresql, the tutorial does state not supported for Mysql

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html

Or it is just null because no data for urls for a particular row?

The attempt to use `getObject` suggested in answer failed with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/postgresql/jdbc4/Jdbc4ResultSet.getObject(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; is abstract
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet.getObject(Jdbc4ResultSet.java)
        at com.jthink.jthinksearch.index.indexer.discogs.ArtistIndex.documentFromResultSet(ArtistIndex.java:209)
        at com.jthink.jthinksearch.index.indexer.discogs.ArtistIndex.indexData(ArtistIndex.java:176)
        at com.jthink.jthinksearch.index.indexer.IndexBuilder.buildDatabaseIndex(IndexBuilder.java:226)
        at com.jthink.jthinksearch.index.indexer.IndexBuilder.buildIndex(IndexBuilder.java:151)
        at com.jthink.jthinksearch.index.indexer.IndexBuilder.main(IndexBuilder.java:119)
```

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: The linked tutorial only calls out lack of support for MySQL and Java DB, because those are also Oracle products. It doesn't mean that all other JDBC drivers do support them, although the [PostgreSQL driver does support arrays](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/arrays.html). The `AbstractMethodError` suggests you are using an old version of the driver (the `getObject` method you tried was introduced in Java 7 / JDBC 4.1), consider upgrading to a newer version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I suggest to use getObject then I removed that because when I try to use `String[] urls = rs.getObject("urls", String[].class);` I get an error `The org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet.getObject (int, Class <T>) function is not yet implemented.` I'm using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901-1.jdbc4 do you have any idea why this error please? I rolledback my solution you can check where it was my mistake maybe

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, use a newer version, like version 42.2.2 (eg https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.2 )

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel now with my solution it gives me `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: conversion to class [Ljava.lang.String; from 2 003 not supported`

Comment: @YCF_L That would seem to indicate that you can't use `getObject` like that ;) I can't help you further, I usually avoid arrays in SQL.

Comment: Ok @MarkRotteveel I see I will remove that part from my answer, thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose because **it is just null because no data for urls for a particular field ?**

To solve your problem you can use :

```
Array urlData = rs.getArray("urls");
String[] urls = urlData != null ? (String[]) urlData.getArray() : null;//or a default value
```

Comment: Maybe I will try again, but getObjects () failed with exception above, not supported by driver

Comment: @PaulTaylor yes I already tried my second solution and it seems that implementation of getObject is not yes complete, but you can solve your problem with the first one

Comment: Thanks you are correct it just failed because there was no data for a row, now working.